# Why doesn't root request get the updated index.html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angularjs, kraken.js

I am developing an angular app. Whenever I modify the index.html, a request to localhost:8000 doesn't get the updated index.html. Why is that? I am using nodejs to host the server. I have tripped over this too many times assuming the request would get the updated index.html, such as including a new script but nothing happens because the index.html isn't the updated one. It is quite annoying every time I refresh I have to type index.html.

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        redirectTo : '/login'
    }).when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'dashboard'
    }).when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'app/layout/login.html'
    }).when('/register', {
        templateUrl: 'app/layout/register.html'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}]);
```

Comment: can you post your RouteProvider

Comment: Can you post the node code that is rendering `index.html`?

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 there isn't any code to render it from node. it is public so it is treated as static resource

Comment: Well, your call to `express.static` then.

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 and we use Kraken.js....kraken does that already for us. Anything I put in public folder is accessible.

Comment: If you're using kraken, tag it as such, please.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably loading from the browser cache rather than the changed copy from the server.

Try

```
location.reload(true)
```

to load it from the server.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload